# Undefined linker symbol at runtime when the symbol equals zero

Tags: c, linker, makefile, undefined-symbol

I am trying to use linker symbols to automatically set a version number in my executables, and it seems to work as long as the symbols aren't set to zero...

In my C code:

```
extern char __VERSION_MAJ;
extern char __VERSION_MIN;

...

printf("Version %u.%u\n", (unsigned) &__VERSION_MAJ, (unsigned) &__VERSION_MIN);
```

And in my makefile:

```
LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --defsym=__VERSION_MAJ=1
LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --defsym=__VERSION_MIN=0
```

Results in the following output when I try to run the executable **test**:

```
./test: symbol lookup error: ./test: undefined symbol: __VERSION_MIN
```

If I change the symbol definition as follows:

```
LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --defsym=__VERSION_MAJ=1
LDFLAGS += -Xlinker --defsym=__VERSION_MIN=1
```

Then it works just fine:

```
Version 1.1
```

I've read about linker symbols here http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/readings/Linker.pdf and trawled google but haven't spotted anything that says 0 is a disallowed value for custom linker symbols.

Also, if I look at the linker map output it does have __VERSION_MIN:

```
0x0000000000000001                __VERSION_MAJ = 0x1
0x0000000000000000                __VERSION_MIN = 0x0
```

So, I'm quite stumped!

I would just use gcc -D__VERSION_MIN=0 instead, but that leads to trickiness and makefile ugliness with using prerequisites to rebuild the application when the version changes (it will be stored in a text file, not hard-coded in the makefile as above.)

I'm compiling and linking with gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) for target i686-linux-gnu, if any of that makes a difference.

Executive summary:

- Should a --defsym expression that results in 0 be allowed?
- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there a better/simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use

```
gcc -D__VERSION_MIN=0
```

then you have to remove the definition from your header file

```
extern char __VERSION_MIN;
```

The

```
gcc -D__VERSION_MIN=0
```

is equivalent to define `__VERSION_MIN` as a macro in your c code

```
#define __VERSION_MIN 0
```

And then you can not define `__VERSION_MIN` twice in your C code

```
extern char __VERSION_MIN;
#define __VERSION_MIN 0
```

This is not allowed

So If you want to use

```
gcc -D__VERSION_MIN=0
```

then you have to remove `extern char __VERSION_MIN;` from your code

Comment: Thanks - yes, if I use the -D alternative then I would indeed remove the other definitions (in fact, I would just do -D__VERSION=\"1.0\" and use it as a string literal).